# How do I determine a dragon's new Challenge Rating when applying the Shadow Dragon template?

Tags: dnd-5e, dragons, character-templates, cr-calculation

The *Monster Manual* contains a template whereby any true dragon may be turned into a [shadow dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/mm/monsters-d#ShadowDragonTemplate). A shadow dragon differs from a true dragon in the following ways:

- It has resistance to necrotic damage always, and resistance to all
  other forms of damage except force, psychic and radiant, when in dim
  light or darkness.
- It has double proficiency in Stealth.
- It can Hide as a bonus action when in dim light or darkness.
- It has sunlight sensitivity (disadvantage on attack rolls and
  Perception checks involving sight when in sunlight).
- The damage type of both the non-piercing portion of its bite, and its breath weapon, is necrotic (regardless of type of dragon).
- Any humanoid brought to 0 hit points by its breath weapon is automatically killed (no death saving throws), and a [shadow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/shadow) rises from its corpse.

Otherwise, the shadow dragon has the same stats as the true dragon. How do you evaluate these differences to come up with a new Challenge Rating? Right now I am specifically looking for the CR of a Black Shadow Dragon Wyrmling, but the best answer will explain how to determine the CR of all types of shadow dragon.

One clue: The *Monster Manual* provides one example stat block for a shadow dragon: a Young Red. The CR of a [Young Red Shadow Dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/young-red-shadow-dragon) is 13, while the CR of a [Young Red Dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/young-red-dragon) is 10. Is merely adding 3 to the CR a good rule of thumb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know I'm a little late to the party here (18 months since OP) but I was searching for this answer also.

Carcer pointed to directions in the DMG, and following them I built a formula that calculates a creature's CR (More or less. It's not an exact science) from their AC, HP, Attack Bonus, Damage per Round, and whether they have significant resistances. I punched in the stats for all the dragons and was pretty happy with the results. I've attached an image of the output table here, in case anyone else stumbles onto this thread like I did.

Thanks Purple Monkey for showing me how to make a MathJax table:

Header Key:
W = Wyrmling.
Y = Young.
A = Adult.
N = Ancient.
S = Shadow Dragon.
L = Dracolich.

\begin{array}{r|llllllllll}
\text{CR by Type} & \text{W} & \text{WS} & \text{Y} & \text{YS} & \text{A} & \text{AL} & \text{AS} & \text{N} & \text{NL} & \text{NS} \\
\hline
Black & 2 & 3 & 7 & 11 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 21 & 22 & 22 \\
Blue & 3 & 4 & 9 & 11 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 23 & 23 & 23 \\
Brass & 1 & 1 & 6 & 10 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 20 & 20 & 21 \\
Bronze & 2 & 3 & 8 & 10 & 15 & 17 & 19 & 22 & 23 & 23 \\
Copper & 1 & 2 & 7 & 10 & 14 & 14 & 16 & 21 & 21 & 21 \\
Gold & 3 & 5 & 10 & 13 & 17 & 19 & 20 & 24 & 24 & 24 \\
Green & 2 & 3 & 8 & 10 & 15 & 16 & 18 & 22 & 21 & 22 \\
Red & 4 & 6 & 10 & 13 & 17 & 19 & 20 & 24 & 25 & 25 \\
Silver & 2 & 4 & 9 & 12 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 23 & 23 & 23 \\
White & 2 & 2 & 6 & 9 & 13 & 15 & 17 & 20 & 20 & 20 \\ \hline
\end{array}

As for the formula I used, it's difficult to transcribe as it frequently points to the lookup table "Monster Statistics By Challenge Rating" on page 274 of the Dungeon Master's Guide, and also the "Effective Hit Points Based on Resistances and Immunities" lookup table from page 277 of the same. I'll do my best to represent it here:

It starts by calculating [EHP] Effective Hit Points from the base monster's [HP] hit points, [CR] challenge rating, and type of "Significant Defense". A monster can have a significant defense type of [N] "None", [R] "Resistance", or [I] "Immune" as seen in the lookup table on 277. Since Shadow Dragons gain an irregular suite of resistances, I added a fourth, less potent option of [S] "Semi-Resistance" specifically for them. SD will equal a modifier between 1 and 2.

\begin{array}{r|lllll}
\text{SD by CR} & \text{N} & \text{S} & \text{R} & \text{I} \\
\hline
1-4 & 1 & 1.5 & 2 & 2 \\
5-10 & 1 & 1.25 & 1.5 & 2 \\
11-16 & 1 & 1 & 1.25 & 1.5 \\
17+ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1.25 \\
\end{array}

$$
\text{EHP} = \text{Ceiling} (\text{HP} \times \text{SD})
$$

[EDCR] Effective Defensive Challenge Rating is a modified base CR found by looking up the EHP value under Hit Points on the 274 table and returning the listed CR.

Next you calculate the [DCR] Defensive Challenge Rating from the monster's EDCR, [AC] base Armor Class, and [EAC] Expected Armor Class. EAC is found by looking up the EDCR value as CR on 274 and returning the listed Armor Class. For every two points the AC is over the EAC, it should increment the DCR by 1.

$$
\text{DCR} = \text{EDCR} + \text{Floor}\left(\frac{\text{AC} - \text{EAC}}{2}\right)
$$

Next you need to calculate the monster's [DPR] Damage Per Round, which should be the maximum damage the monster can deal in a turn. Assume that a small area of effect attack will hit two targets, and a large one will hit three. Since a dragons breath weapon can't be used every turn and has a 1/3 chance of recharging, calculate the the [DBW] Damage of the Breath Weapon and the [DOA] Damage of Other Attacks separately.

$$
\text{DPR} = \frac{\text{DBW} + \text{DOA} + \text{DOA}}{3}
$$

[EOCR] Effective Offensive Challenge Rating is a modified base CR found by looking up the DPR value as Damage/Round on 274 and return the listed CR.

Next you calculate the [OCR] Offensive Challenge Rating from the monster's EOCR, [AB] base Attack Bonus, and [EAB] Expected Attack Bonus. EAB is found by looking up the EOCR value as CR on 274 and returning the listed Attack Bonus. For every two points the AB is over the EAB, it should increment the OCR by 1.

$$
\text{OCR} = \text{EOCR} + \text{Floor}\left(\frac{\text{AB} - \text{EAB}}{2}\right)
$$

The final Challenge Rating is the rounded average of DCR and ACR.

$$
\text{CR} = \text{Round}\left(\frac{\text{DCR} + \text{OCR}}{2}\right)
$$

---

You may now see why I didn't post the "formula" the first time, as it five times references lookup tables (six times, if you include finding the base CR from HP). Plus, it took me six hours to get it all together and working and I was too burnt out to "show my work". I hope this was helpful to someone.

Comment: I decided to change the accepted answer to this one, as the table is most helpful, and I don't see any issues with the reasoning.

Answer (score 11):

## Use the DMG's guidance on modifying monsters

The DMG, on pages 273 through 279, includes guidance on modifying monsters and creating new monsters, including guidelines on how to calculate a monster's effective CR. This involves breaking down the monster's capabilities into a "defensive" challenge rating and an "offensive" challenge rating, then averaging the two.

### Young red shadow dragons

A young red dragon has a normal CR of 10. By following the DMG's guidance on calculating its defensive CR, we see that:

- It has 178hp, which looks up to CR 8 in the table
- It has an AC of 18, 2 points higher than the expected AC of 16 for a CR 8 creature, so bumps CR to 9
- It doesn't have lots of damage resistances or immunities, so we don't treat it as having more HP for these calculations

For the DCR and OCR to average to 10, I'll assume the offensive CR is 11.

The single biggest difference adding the Shadow Dragon template to the dragon makes is to add lots of resistances that make it very hard to hurt (maybe only resistances it has in certain conditions... but then why would it ever stick around to fight you if it wasn't in advantageous terrain?) By adding so many resistances we justify raising the dragon's effective HP for the purpose of calculating its CR, as per Step 9 of the guidance on page 277:

- 178hp is CR 8
- Multiply HP by x1.5, for a CR 9 creature with many resistances, to give ~267hp
- 267hp is CR 14 (and AC 18 is appropriate for a CR 14 creature)

Averaging DCR 14 with an OCR of 11 gives us CR 13. It's plausible that the dragon's OCR was also given a slight bump because of the way its breath weapon can instantly kill adventurers now (the changes to damage type wouldn't normally make any change to its CR), which does make it meaningfully more lethal than the base creature - but OCR 12 would also average to CR 13 here.

At any rate, the change to the young red dragon's CR when applying the shadow dragon template as given in the Monster Manual seems consistent with the DMG's guidance on calculating CR when modifying/creating monsters.

### So what of the Black Dragon Wyrmling?

This is a little harder to calculate since the wyrmling's stats are at the very low end of the scale and the DMG isn't super clear about whether or not CR changes should be steps on the table or full points, but we'll give it a go:

A Shadow Black Dragon Wyrmling's defensive CR:

- 33hp maps to CR 1/8
- AC 17 is 4 points higher so bumps CR two points to 2 (2 1/8) or 1/2 (two steps up from 1/8)
- For a CR <4 creature with many resistances, multiply HP by x2, so 66hp
- 66hp maps to... CR 1/2, again bumped by the higher AC by two points - to 3 (2 1/2) or 2 (two steps up)

And offensively:

- ~21 damage per round (assuming one use of breath weapon hitting two targets and two bite attacks over a three round period, as per DMG's guidance) maps to CR 3
- +4 to hit is appropriate for CR 3 so no change

Averaging those gives us CR 3. (Note that the base creature could be CR 3 or CR 2 depending on how we calculated it - as the MM gives it CR 2, that suggests the second method of stepping on the table rather than adding entire points is the better one.)

Fact is, the shadow dragon template doesn't make the black dragon wyrmling effectively that much more durable - it's maybe twice as hard to kill as it was before on paper, but against a normal adventuring party that change in effective hit points would probably only give it one more round of life.

The change to the breath weapon is probably the most significant factor in this case, since at the low levels where a CR 2 or 3 creature is an appropriate challenge, 5d8 damage could easily one shot a character and then they're dead outright. Bumping the OCR by a point to account for this gives us DCR 3 and OCR 4 which averages to 4 (3 1/2) - so 3 to 4 would seem a reasonable CR for the shadow black dragon wyrmling.

Of course, the DMG is quick to point out that the guidelines it provides are just that, and you may need to adjust the CR of a creature if it proves to be more or less dangerous in actual play. Many monsters in the published material have challenge ratings which are slightly off from what you would calculate from the DMG's guidance because of their special abilities and features that change the effective challenge they provide.

Answer (score 0):

## Use relative XP

As was indicated in the question, (MM, 84):

> When a dragon becomes a shadow dragon, it retains its statistics except as described below.

*Challenge Rating* is not listed as one of the exceptions.

A strict reading would indicate that you keep the same CR when the dragon transforms.  The *Monster Manual* describes what a statistic is on page 6:

> A monster's statistics, sometimes referred to as its stat block, provide the essential information that you need to run the monster.

Under the broad heading of ***Statistics*** you will find many different stats including *Challenge Rating* (MM 9, under sub-heading *Challenge*).

So the rules indicate the CR stays the same, however the authors have provided a template which increases the CR of the *Young Red Dragon* from 10 to 13 after it was transformed to a *Young Red Shadow Dragon*.

### Why the discrepancy?

I don't know.  But it's there.  More importantly, if it's an oversight, where did the authors make the error?  Is the error in not including CR as an exception, or is the error in changing the CR in the template?  Or maybe there is no error and I'm missing something (?).

Considering that CR ***tells you how great a threat the monster is,*** (MM 9) we need to determine if the stats gained by the *Young Red Shadow Dragon* make it more formidable than the standard *Young Red Dragon.* Once we determine this we can know where the error is in the text.

What makes the Shadow Dragon more formidable than it's former self?:

- If the Shadow Dragon is in dim light or darkness it has resistance to all damage types except force, radiant or psychic.  That's a huge benefit.
- With its hide abiity as a bonus action in dim light or darkness, *and* extra stealth abilities (+8) it is far more likely the Shadow Dragon will surprise a party of adventurers.
- The Shadow Dragon's breath weapon instantly kills a combatant who falls to 0 HP, removing the *death saving throw* mechanic.
- *And* an *Undead Shadow* (MM 269) immediately rises from that dead combatant's corpse to do the dragon's bidding.

The only negative impact is that the Shadow Dragon is at disadvantage on attack rolls *if* it is in sunlight.

## The Young Red Shadow Dragon *is* more formidable than the Young Red Dragon.

It seems that the error is in not including the CR in the list of exceptions.  Is the *Young Red Shadow Dragon* deserving of +3 CR?  Yes, this seems about right, however as a general rule I would not add +3 CR to a *Shadow Dragon*.  A more accurate adjustment would be to take the relative XP increase from the template and apply the CR based on the XP increase.

### Doing the math.

The standard *Young Red Dragon* has an XP of 5,900, while the *Young Red Shadow Dragon* is indicated as having an XP of 10,000. The XP has increased by a factor of 1.694915, that's 10,000/5,900.  I'd call it 1.7.  Apply that to the 450 XP of the *Black Dragon Wyrmling* and you get 450 x 1.7 = 765. Looking at the XP/CR chart at the front of the MM shows us that 765 XP is a CR of 3.

**The *Black Shadow Dragon Wyrmling* would have a CR of 3.**

I can guarantee you though: that beast is staying in its lair and *never* going out in sunlight without SPF *I don't think so*.

One final point is that according to its description, ***The Shadow dragon might retain or lose any or all of its lair actions or inherit new ones, as the DM sees fit.***  This could also increase or decrease the CR and would depend on the changes made.  Of course this only applies to Dragons that already have a lair action (*or does it?* But I'll leave that for another question).

Comment: Can you explain why you think that multiplying the CR by a factor is a "more accurate adjustment" than a flat +3? Moreover, how does either method compare with Creating a Monster Stat Block (DMG pp275), which includes instructions to calculate CR?